# woocommerce add to cart button not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

im new to wordpress theme development so please take my question as simple answer  .... the issue here is when i try to make add to cart button i get 'read more' link instead , not sure where the problem is but i looked online and found this code multiple times but its not working for me ... do i need to edit the functions.php ? or am i missing something here ? .... heres my code within the loop:

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" class="button  product_type_%s">%s</a>',
    esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
    esc_attr( $product->id ),
    $product->is_purchasable() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
    esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
),$product );
```

Comment: Add to cart button it's only displayed for simple products type that are in stock…

Comment: add to cart button is never showing but 'review product' instead for all products type

Comment: i tried to wrap  <a href="?add-to-cart={product_id}"></a> within the button it worked somehow but it redirects me to the shop page so the user lose the current browsing location

Comment: Add to cart button it's only display when your Product Price is inserted

Comment: yes the price is inserted in all products and are showing in the loop ... but the button not working :(

Comment: Have you figured this out? Was your product a simple or variable product?

Answer (score 0):

I think, actions are conflicted somewhere. Try to find add_action('','',\d\d) somewhere and try to let that last digits not to be the same

Comment: Please do not add comments as answers. Use the comments section for that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34835565)